# Load data from one worksheet to another using AdvancedFilter

Tags: excel, vba, loops

I'm trying to create two loops: one loop between row 8 and 17 and another loop between row 19 and 27 of the worksheet Invoice. I want to copy whetever data I have in those rows to the worksheet Invoice Items. If I type, for instance the number "03" in the cell H1 it automaticly loads all the data regarding the invoice #3 from Invoice Items worksheet do the Invoice worksheet.
Here are my problems:  - It copys as it should but I'm having trouble loading the data. It only loads the data of the first column instead of the two columns. - Since I have two columns, I want when I type something in the row 8 and row 19 of the Invoice workseeht to be copyied in the same row in the Invoice Items. But if, for example, I type something in the row 8 and 9 and 19, I want that data of row 8 and 19 to be copied on the same row but the data of the row 9 to be copied on the row below 8. I really need you guys help please. Below is my full code and  [print screen of the both worksheets](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GxShX.png). Thank you

```
Sub Invoice_SaveUpdate() 
Dim InvRow As Long, InvItemRow As Long, LastItemRow As Long, ItemRow As Long, LastOtherItemRow As Long, OtherItemRow As Long, OtherInvItemRow As Long
 With Sheet1
'Determine New or Existing Invoice
If .Range("B4").Value = True Then 'New Invoice
    InvRow = Sheet2.Range("A99999").End(xlUp).Row + 1  'First Available Row
    .Range("H1").Value = .Range("B6").Value 'Add Invoice Number
    Sheet2.Range("A" & InvRow).Value = .Range("B6").Value 'Add Invoice #
Else: 'Existing Invoice
    InvRow = .Range("B3").Value 'Existing Invoice Row
End If
Sheet2.Range("B" & InvRow).Value = .Range("H2").Value 'Date
Sheet2.Range("C" & InvRow).Value = .Range("E3").Value 'Customer Name
Sheet2.Range("D" & InvRow).Value = .Range("H30").Value 'Invoice Total

'Add / Update Invoice Items
LastItemRow = .Range("D17").End(xlUp).Row  'Last Invoice Item Row
If LastItemRow < 8 Then GoTo NoItems
For ItemRow = 8 To LastItemRow
    If .Range("I" & ItemRow).Value <> Empty Then 'existing Row
        InvItemRow = .Range("I" & ItemRow).Value
    Else 'New Row
         InvItemRow = Sheet3.Range("A9999").End(xlUp).Row + 1   'First AvailRow
         Sheet3.Range("A" & InvItemRow).Value = .Range("H1").Value  'Invoice #
         .Range("I" & ItemRow).Value = InvItemRow 'Invoice Item Row
         Sheet3.Range("G" & InvItemRow).Value = "=Row()" 'Add Row #
    End If
    Sheet3.Range("B" & InvItemRow & ":E" & InvItemRow).Value = .Range("D" & ItemRow & ":G" & ItemRow).Value 'Add Desc, Qty, Price
    Sheet3.Range("F" & InvItemRow).Value = ItemRow
Next ItemRow

    LastOtherItemRow = .Range("D27").End(xlUp).Row 'Last Invoice Item Row
    If LastOtherItemRow < 19 Then GoTo NoItems
For OtherItemRow = 19 To LastOtherItemRow
    If .Range("I" & OtherItemRow).Value <> Empty Then 'existing Row
        OtherInvItemRow = .Range("I" & OtherItemRow).Value
    Else 'New Row
         OtherInvItemRow = Sheet3.Range("A9999").End(xlUp).Row  'First AvailRow
         Sheet3.Range("A" & OtherInvItemRow).Value = .Range("H1").Value  'Invoice #
         .Range("I" & OtherItemRow).Value = OtherInvItemRow 'Invoice Item Row
         Sheet3.Range("M" & OtherInvItemRow).Value = "=Row()" 'Add Row #
    End If
    Sheet3.Range("H" & OtherInvItemRow & ":K" & OtherInvItemRow).Value = .Range("D" & OtherItemRow & ":G" & OtherItemRow).Value 'Add Desc, Qty, Price
    Sheet3.Range("L" & OtherInvItemRow).Value = OtherItemRow
Next OtherItemRow
NoItems:
.Range("B4").Value = False 'Set new invoice to false
.Shapes("CancelNewBtn").Visible = msoFalse
.Shapes("AddNewBtn").Visible = msoCTrue
 End With
 End Sub

 Sub Invoice_New()
 With Sheet1
.Range("B4").Value = True 'Set new Invoice to true
.Range("H1,E3,E4,E5,D8:H17,D19:H27,I8:I27").ClearContents 'Clear Invoice Fields
.Range("H2").Value = Now
.Shapes("CancelNewBtn").Visible = msoCTrue
.Shapes("AddNewBtn").Visible = msoFalse
 End With
 End Sub

 Sub Invoice_Load()
 Dim InvRow As Long, InvItemRow As Long, LastInvItemRow As Long, OtherLastInvItemRow As Long,     OtherLastItemResultRow As Long, OtherResultRow As Long, OtherInvItemRow As Long
  Dim ResultRow As Long, LastItemResultRow As Long
 With Sheet1
If .Range("B3").Value = Empty Then
    MsgBox "Please select a correct Invoice #"
    Exit Sub
End If
InvRow = .Range("B3").Value  'Invoice Row
.Range("E3,E4,E5,D8:H17,D19:H27,I8:I27").ClearContents 'Clear Invoice Fields
.Range("B5").Value = True 'Set Invoice Load To True
.Range("H2").Value = Sheet2.Range("B" & InvRow).Value 'Date
.Range("E3").Value = Sheet2.Range("C" & InvRow).Value 'Customer

'Load Invoice Items
 LastInvItemRow = Sheet3.Range("A9999").End(xlUp).Row  'Last Item Row
 If LastInvItemRow < 3 Then GoTo NoItems
  Sheet3.Range("A2:M" & LastInvItemRow).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy,    CriteriaRange:=Sheet3.Range("O2:O3"), CopyToRange:=Sheet3.Range("Q2:AC2"), Unique:=False
  LastItemResultRow = Sheet3.Range("Q9999").End(xlUp).Row
  If LastItemResultRow < 3 Then GoTo NoItems
 For ResultRow = 3 To LastItemResultRow
  InvItemRow = Sheet3.Range("V" & ResultRow).Value 'Invoice Row
 .Range("D" & InvItemRow & ":G" & InvItemRow).Value = Sheet3.Range("R" & ResultRow & ":U" &  ResultRow).Value 'Item, Desc, Qty, Price
 .Range("I" & InvItemRow).Value = Sheet3.Range("W" & ResultRow).Value 'Bring over item row
 Next ResultRow

OtherLastInvItemRow = Sheet3.Range("A9999").End(xlUp).Row  'Last Item Row
If OtherLastInvItemRow < 3 Then GoTo NoItems
Sheet3.Range("A2:M" & OtherLastInvItemRow).AdvancedFilter xlFilterCopy,    CriteriaRange:=Sheet3.Range("O2:O3"), CopyToRange:=Sheet3.Range("Q2:AC2"), Unique:=False
 OtherLastItemResultRow = Sheet3.Range("Q9999").End(xlUp).Row
 If OtherLastItemResultRow < 3 Then GoTo NoItems
 For OtherResultRow = 3 To OtherLastItemResultRow
 OtherInvItemRow = Sheet3.Range("AB" & OtherResultRow).Value 'Invoice Row
.Range("D" & OtherInvItemRow & ":G" & OtherInvItemRow).Value = Sheet3.Range("X" & OtherResultRow  & ":AA" & OtherResultRow).Value 'Item, Desc, Qty, Price
.Range("I" & OtherInvItemRow).Value = Sheet3.Range("AC" & OtherResultRow).Value 'Bring over item  row
 Next OtherResultRow


NoItems:
.Range("B4").Value = False 'Set new invoice to false
.Range("B5").Value = False 'Set Invoice Load To False
 .Shapes("CancelNewBtn").Visible = msoFalse
 .Shapes("AddNewBtn").Visible = msoCTrue
 End With
 End Sub

Sub Invoice_CancelNew()
If Sheet2.Range("A3").Value <> Empty Then Sheet1.Range("H1").Value = Sheet2.Range("A3").Value
End Sub
```

Comment: I cannot set up an example to mimic yours, but what happens if, for the `CopyToRange` you specify just a single cell (upper left corner of destination)?

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I'm sorry but dont understand what you mean.

Comment: Oh, I thought you were having problems with pasting the results of the `AdvancedFilter`. If that is not the case, forget my suggestion.